# vector represented by standard basis

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

let us consider following problem
[image]

i want to clarify one thing,namely   vector $v=(a,b,0)$   satisfy yes  this condition?or is there any other thing asked? generally  every  $v$ in $R^3$   is represented by

$v=v_1*i+v_2*j+v_3*k$
i have tried figure out  what combination of $m$ and $n$ cancel out   $z$ component?only possible is  this vector be parallel to  $z$ axis right?so  $m$ and $n$ must make  vector parallel to  $z$ axis right?

Comment: I find your wording confusing. As for the question in the image, consider $0\cdot \mathrm i+0\cdot \mathrm j+1\cdot \mathrm k$.

Comment: Yes, there is something else asked, not just about $(a,b,0)$.

Comment: then what is asked about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking: Can every vector $(a,b,c)$ be written as combinations of just $i$ and $j$?

So what you have to ask yourself is "Can we get a $z$-component by just adding $i$ and $j$ vectors?".

Comment: if $c$ is $0$ ,then no problem related to  this question right?

Comment: They are asking if *every* vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as a combination of $i$ and $j$. This means you can't put conditions on $c$ since there *are* vectors in that space with nonzero $z$-component. Think of it this way, $(1,2,3)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can this be written using just the $i$ and $j$ basis vectors?

Comment: no because,three  basis $i,j,k$ are independent from each other,is not correct?

Comment: Thats  true but its also what your being asked to prove.  You are almost there, you already showed that $a \hat{i} = b \hat{j} = (a,b,0)$ right? How does this show that $i$ and $j$ are independent of $k$? In other words how does it show that we can't produce the vector $(1,2,3)$ with just $i$ and $j$? There is basically just one sentence left and you have it.

Comment: so introudece that $i=(1,0,0)$,$j=(0,1,0)$,$k=(0,0,1)$ right?so consider  $c*i+d*j+m*k=0$ implies that $c=d=m=0$

Comment: Yes you start there and then show that using just the first two you can't produce every vector in the space. The easiest way to do this is to pick a specific vector (1,2,3) or something and show that it cannot be expressed using just $i$ and $j$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11040/discussion-between-spencer-and-dato)

Comment: thanks my friend for helping